# UIImageView frame aspect ratio fault?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a UIImageView that I want to automatically adjust its size varying on the device its being ran on, my application is universal meaning 4s-ipad Air. It seems every combination of Auto Layout constrain I attempt, there's a conflict. What combination of constrains should I use to center this ImageView in the container as well as make it adjust its size?

**update**

So Everything looks perfect in the preview below:

[image]

but when i run it on iphone 4S, its not there, and when I change the orientation on any other screen it disappears, what would be a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using relative constraints to solve this problem:

[image: all]

It will allow you to specify all the sizes not explicitly but using multipliers, as a percentage of the sizes of superview.

Leading constraint:

[image: leading]

Width constraint:

[image: width]

Top constraint:

[image: top]